# Boost 1.48 compilation in Linux - get the compiler name in the output files with Bjam?

Tags: linux, boost, bjam

I am trying to compile the Boost 1.48 in CentOS 5.6. I need the files to be in this format:

```
boost_program_options-gcc41-mt-1_48
```

I am compiling with this bjam flags:

```
./b2 -q --toolset=gcc --layout=tagged --without-mpi install
```

but it still don't add the `gcc` prefix to the name. 
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

For me (although I use darwin toolset instead of plain gcc) Bjam creates files with names, like:

```
libboost_program_options-xgcc42-mt-1_49.a
```

Create the `site-config.jam` or `user-config.jam` file, which defines your custom version of GCC toolset, as described in ['Configuration' section](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/overview/configuration.html) of the Boost.Build documentation.

Additionally, there is an example, which suggests, that standard GCC toolset has version names defined as numbers only, without the `gcc` prefix.

Boost output filenames are generated, by the `tag` rule in `boostcpp.jam`. You can check there, if the above solution would be insufficient